# Phone stuck in fastboot mode, can't boot into OS or Recovery mode and flashing stock rom doesn't help

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, boot, unbricking

When I tried to reboot my phone a few days ago, it booted into CSC fastboot mode and it couldn't boot into the OS. I tried Vol down + power off combo to boot into recovery but that doesn't work and after showing the Android Phone screen, it just powers off again.

The CSC fastboot screen is the same as on this image of another phone (same model) having the same issue:

[image]

I unlocked the bootloader using fastboot and now it shows FASTBOOT instead of CSC FASTBOOT.

[image]

`fastboot getvar all` shows 'unlocked: yes', so the bootloader is definitely unlocked.

Then I flashed the stock rom for my phone and even after successfully flashing all required img files, I still cannot boot successfully. I tried this procedure multiple times but nothing works.

I also can't boot into recovery after flashing stock recovery.img or even compatible twrp versions. Flashing works successfully but it shows FAILED when trying to boot. 
After leaving the phone alone for a day, I connected it to the pc using the usb cable this morning and the battery charging animation showed up and it showed the Bootloader unlocked warning with 'press power off to pause boot'

[image]

I got excited or something and pressed the power off button. It then booted into the fastboot mode again as usual. But now it briefly shows the battery animation when I connect it to the charger when it's switched off, and it boots into fastboot mode again.

I tried re-locking the bootloader and trying it again, same with locking it and nothing works. Neither does trying to flash or boot recovery/twrp, or flashing the stock rom again.

The volume buttons are working fine and there was no problem with them before as well. I also opened the device and tried pressing the buttons manually and got the same result.

`fastboot getvar all` output:

[image]

Comment: its good you unlocked bootloader, keep it unlocked! can you boot twrp from fastboot?

Comment: No. I can't boot either twrp or stock recovery from fastboot.

Comment: `fastboot format:ext4 cache userdata` worked successfully, so did flashing boot recovery, system and vendor. 
`fastboot --set-active=b` returned error: Device does not support slots.

I've also tried 4 different usb cables but it's the same result. The phone is also a little less than 2 years old.

Comment: I believe so, yes. I've added the output to the question.

Comment: Seems as if flashing to partitions like boot, vendor, recovery, mdtp isn't being successfully done even though the flashing runs fine. I manually tried to flash boot.img using `fastboot flash boot boot.img` to see if the partition shows up in `fastboot getvar all`:

target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes  
sending 'boot' (46561 KB)...  
OKAY [  1.117s]  
writing 'boot'...  
OKAY [  0.031s]  
finished. total time: 1.189s  

but the only partitions mentioned are cache, userdata and system, like before. Flashing this rom worked for other people who had the same issue.

Comment: I got the device to finally boot. `fastboot boot boot.img` or `fastboot boot recovery.img` never worked but the flashing worked. Now, I just flashed boot.img and entered `fastboot continue` and it finally worked! I still don't know why it couldn't boot the image after flashing normally or show the partition in getvar. Thanks for pointing me to the missing partitions, it really helped!

Comment: Although I guess this way I'd have to use `fastboot continue` to boot up whenever I have to restart my phone.

Comment: try `fastboot flashing unlock_critical` or something and try to flash all partitions again

Comment: No luck. Either there's some issue with the volume button or something's just wrecked. For now, I'll just stick to `fastboot continue` whenever to restart, and back up everything using twrp (just in case) which I can run by flashing it as boot and `fastboot continue` and then doing the same with the original boot image when I'm done with twrp.

Comment: What is your cell model so we could help with stock or twrp backup